# Unwanted default reviewer when creating a pull request in TFS/Git 2018

Tags: git, tfs

In TFS 2018 (Specifically, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 16.131.27701.1) with Git, whenever I create a pull request, default team of the project is automatically assigned by default. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Dev sometimes forget to remove the default team and then the whole team get email notification asking for reviewing the code.

[image]

I found this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/241804/unwanted-default-reviewers-are-being-added-to-pull.html from Microsoft. Per their recommendation, I added individual code reviewers like below, but the default team still shows up.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a by designed behavior at TFS version 2018.

It will auto adds the **project team** as a reviewer irrespective of the repo you've selected.

However, for Azure DevOps 2019 and Azure DevOps Service, no reviewers are added by default at present. It's released with **New Navigation**.

[image]

Detail explanation as below:

> When we first launched the pull request (PR) experience, we thought it
>   would make sense to assign all PRs to the team context that you had
>   selected when creating the PR. This behavior has been a frustration
>   point, since many people did not notice the connection between the
>   team context and the PR assignment. In fact, this has been one of our
>   top UserVoice suggestions.
>
> As part of the new navigation changes, we took the opportunity to
>   change this default association with teams. You'll notice two changes:
>
> 1. When creating a PR, **no reviewers are added by default.** The reviewers
>      list does have a feature to make it easier to add individuals and
>      groups that were added to PRs recently. The required reviewers
>      policy can also help teams that want to ensure that specific
>      reviewers are added to review their code.
> 2. ...

More detail please take a look at this official release: [creates a PR without a default team as reviewer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/jul-10-vsts#create-pull-requests-without-a-default-team-as-reviewer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Two follow up questions - 1) Is there any plan to fix this issue in TFS 2018? 2) Is Azure DevOps 2019 next version of TFS 2018? That is, can I just upgrade the existing TFS 2018 to Azure DevOps 2019 just like upgrading from TFS 2015 to 2018?

Comment: @JerryHan 1) Afraid not, I didn't see any related doc said that. Since it's an older design. Actually if a new TFS version provide some new feature, we usually suggest users to upgrade to new version. Sorry for any inconvenience 2) Yes Azure DevOps 2019 is just next version of TFS 2018, we change the name from TFS to Azure DevOps Server, VSTS to Azure DevOps Service. It's quite easy to upgrade from TFS2018 to Azure DevOps 2019. Even no need to upgrade sql server only needed to touch the “Application Tier”. https://blog.codeinside.eu/2019/04/30/update-onprem-tfs-2018-to-azuredevops-server-2019/